# How to show avatar url in v-checkbox?

Tags: image, vue.js, vuetify.js

i want to show user's avatar when create chat group with v-checkbox.What should i do?

i am tring to change v-checkbox value, but it doesn't work

```
<v-checkbox v-model="selected"
                        v-for="(user, index) in users"
                        :key="index"
                        :label="user.display_name"
                        :value="user.uuid"
            ></v-checkbox>
```

where to setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is user's avatar an image? Then you can use label slot:

```
<v-checkbox v-model="selected"
    v-for="(user, index) in users"
    :key="index"
    :value="user.uuid">
    <template v-slot:label>
       <img src="..." alt="Profile Image"/>
    </template>
</v-checkbox>
```